# I have problem with @ViewModelInject in hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, clean-architecture, dagger-hilt

I get this error when i use @viewmodelinject in hilt

```
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.example.domain.repositories.QuestionRepo cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method]
```

my viewmodel class

```
class MainViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(

private val questionUseCaseImpl: QuestionUseCaseImpl,

): ViewModel(),LifecycleObserver {
val questionModel = MutableLiveData<QuestionModel>()
private val compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()

fun getData() {
    questionUseCaseImpl.execute()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe({
            it?.let {
                questionModel.postValue(it)
            }
        },{

        }).let {
            compositeDisposable.add(it)
        }
}

override fun onCleared() {
    super.onCleared()
    compositeDisposable.clear()
}
```

my repository class in domain module

```
interface QuestionRepo{

    fun getQuestion(): Single<QuestionModel>
}
```

my repositoryimpl class in data module

```
    class QuestionRepoImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val questionMapper: dagger.Lazy<QuestionMapper>,
    private val service: Service
):QuestionRepo {
    override fun getQuestion(): Single<QuestionModel> {
        return service.getQuestion().map {
            questionMapper.get().toMapper(it)
        }
```

my usecaseimpl class in domain module

```
class QuestionUseCaseImpl @Inject constructor(private val questionRepo: QuestionRepo):

QuestionUseCase<QuestionModel>{
override fun execute(): Single<QuestionModel> {
   return questionRepo.getQuestion()
}
```

Comment: Did you create a `@Module`? It's the last step in the quick start guide: https://dagger.dev/hilt/quick-start

Comment: yes I created but still doesn't work

Comment: I believe you need `@Binds` for interfaces, take a look [here](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android?authuser=2#inject-interfaces). If not you's use `@Provides` to give hilt an idea as to how to create an instance.

Comment: How are you injecting your `QuestionRepo` inteface? you need to provide Hilt with the way you create your interface with `@Provides` annotated method in your Hilt Module. For example: `@Provides fun provideQuestionRepo():QuestionRepo = // create your QuestionRepoImpl object here`